# Checkbox checked add class

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to add a class to my label of my checkbox if it's checked.

Heres my html

```
<ul class="checkbox-list">
    <li><label class="rounded-all">Google <input class="checkbox-row" name="google" type="checkbox" value=""></label></li>
    <li><label class="rounded-all">Bing <input class="checkbox-row" name="bing" type="checkbox" value=""></label></li>
    <li><label class="rounded-all">Facebook <input class="checkbox-row" name="facebook" type="checkbox" value=""></label> </li> 
</ul>
```

I tried with this piece of code i got off here but doesn't seem too do the trick:

```
$(".checkbox-row").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.checkbox-list li label').toggleClass("selected", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3nK5A/).  What's likely happening is your CSS selector for your `.selected` class isn't specific enough, and so the properties just aren't getting applied.

For example, this may not work (if say there was a `.checkbox-list li label` style defined with another color):

```
.selected { color: red; }
```

While a more specific selector would:

```
.checkbox-list li label.selected { color: red; }
```

---

It's worth nothing though, your [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) call can be simplified a bit using just `label`:

```
$(".checkbox-row").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("selected", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. Like you say i just had to simplify the CSS class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".checkbox-row").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); 
    else 
        $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: This will add the class to the `<li>`, not the `<label>`.

Comment: No it won't - Direct parent of the input is the label.